# Azure DevOps Self Hosted Agents VMSS: Unable to locate executable file: 'unzip'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have created the VMSS in Azure

```
az group create --location eastus --name vmssagents

az vmss create --name vmssagentspool --resource-group vmssagents --image UbuntuLTS --vm-sku Standard_B1s --storage-sku StandardSSD_LRS --authentication-type SSH --generate-ssh-keys --instance-count 2 --disable-overprovision --upgrade-policy-mode manual --single-placement-group false --platform-fault-domain-count 1 --load-balancer ""
```

and created the Self Hosted Agent Pool in Azure DevOps

[image]

However, it is throwing the below error

> Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'unzip'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

Below is the Pipeline definition

```
trigger: none

pool: 'Self Hosted'

variables:
  bkstrgrg: azDevTFTestRG
  bkstrg: cirazadopstest2
  bkcontainer: tfstate
  bkstrgkey: devpipeline.terraform.tfstate

stages:
  - stage: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: validate
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            displayName: tfinstall
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskv3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              backendServiceArm: 'Azure-Landing-Zone-Deployment'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(bkstrgrg)'
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(bkstrg)'
              backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(bkcontainer)'
              backendAzureRmKey: '$(bkstrgkey)'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'

  - stage: tfdeploy
    condition: succeeded ('tfvalidate')
    dependsOn: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: apply
        steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            displayName: tfinstall
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskv3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              backendServiceArm: 'Azure-Landing-Zone-Deployment'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(bkstrgrg)'
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(bkstrg)'
              backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(bkcontainer)'
              backendAzureRmKey: '$(bkstrgkey)'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'

          - task: TerraformTaskv3@3
            displayName: plan
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'plan'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'Azure-Landing-Zone-Deployment'

          - task: TerraformTaskv3@3
            displayName: apply
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'apply'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'Azure-Landing-Zone-Deployment'
```

**Update:** As suggested in the answer, I have recreated the VMSS with the below custom extension

```
az vmss extension set --vmss-name vmssagentspool --resource-group vmssagents  --name CustomScript --version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings '{"fileUris":["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kavija/azure-devops-custom-installers/main/zip_install.sh"],"commandToExecute":"bash ./zip_install.sh" }'
```

Comment: Start first by interactively accessing your self hosted agent and check if package is absent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the two workaround below.

1.You could add a bash command `$ sudo apt-get install unzip` before the failed task or at the beginning of your pipeline.

2.You could add an Azure VMSS extension to run the command `sudo apt-get install unzip` once the VMSS instance is created, and run the pipeline again. You could follow the steps below.
1)Create a .sh file in your public github repo with the command of `sudo apt-get install unzip`
2)Go to your VMSS resource and follow the three steps in the pic below

```
//script in step 2
az vmss extension set --vmss-name ubuntu --resource-group {Your Res Group} --name CustomScript --version 2.0 --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --settings '{ \"fileUris\":[\"https://{YourPublicRepo}/AddUnzip.sh\"], \"commandToExecute\": \"bash ./AddUnzip.sh /myArgs \" }'
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the Azure Vmss extension?

Comment: @MugilKarthikeyan I have updated my answer for your reference